# probability model in kernlab::ksvm

Tags: r, svm, kernlab

For classification tasks in `kernlab::ksvm`, the default SVM used is C-svm (LIBSVM, Chang & Lin), which calculates a binary classification task. This can be extended to multiclass problems by calculating multiple 1 vs many binary classifiers and aggregating the results. Native multiclass classification is supported via spoc-svm (Crammer, Singer) and via kbb-svm (Weston, Watkins).

These are supported in `kernlab` via the `type` parameter in `ksvm` (see `?kernlab::ksvm`):

```
ksvm(..., type= "C-svc", ...)
ksvm(..., type= "spoc-svc", ...)
ksvm(..., type= "kbb-svc", ...)
```

However, prediction probabilities are only available via C-svm. **Why? Is this an error in the implementation?**

```
library(kernlab)
data(iris)
# default - C-svc allows for a prob.model
k1 <- ksvm(Species ~. ,data= iris, 
           type= "C-svc",
           prob.model=TRUE,
           kernel= "rbfdot", C= 1)

p1 <- predict(k1, iris, type= "probabilities") # works

#### non default, doesn't work:
k1 <- ksvm(Species ~. ,data= iris, 
           type= "spoc-svc",
           prob.model=TRUE,
           kernel= "rbfdot", C= 1)

p1 <- predict(k1, iris, type= "probabilities")
Error in .local(object, ...) : 
  ksvm object contains no probability model. Make sure you set the paramater    prob.model in ksvm during training.

k1 <- ksvm(Species ~. ,data= iris, 
           type= "kbb-svc",
           prob.model=TRUE,
           kernel= "rbfdot", C= 1)

p1 <- predict(k1, iris, type= "probabilities")
Error in .local(object, ...) : 
  ksvm object contains no probability model. Make sure you set the paramater prob.model in ksvm during training.
```

The documentation does not note this or provide any guidelines. As you can see, the parameter `prob.model` has been specified in the function call. At a minimum, this appears to be a problematic error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kernlab` currently does not support probability estimation for types other than `C-svc`, `nu-svc` and `C-bsvc` ([check the code](https://github.com/cran/kernlab/blob/master/R/ksvm.R#L2763)).

```
if(type == "probabilities")
{ 
  if(is.null(prob.model(object)[[1]]))
    stop("ksvm object contains no probability model. Make sure you set the paramater prob.model in ksvm during training.")

  if(type(object)=="C-svc"||type(object)=="nu-svc"||type(object)=="C-bsvc")
    {
        [...]
    }
  else
    stop("probability estimates only supported for C-svc, C-bsvc and nu-svc")
}
```

---

The problem is native multiclass solutions lack the binary probabilities that go as input into `couple`. Actually, coding your own solution wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Where would one start looking in order to code multiclass SVM probability models please?

Comment: Can't edit my previous because it has been > 5 mins. It seems like the best way to go is the implementation by Wu _et al._, _J Mach Learn Res_, 5, 2004 http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/wu04a/wu04a.pdf